# MySQL weird error. duplicate entry for primary key

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

I got sql error today:

> Duplicate entry '10639' for key 'PRIMARY'INSERT INTO site_plugin_redirects_stats (stat_redirect,stat_date,stat_from,stat_ip) VALUES ( 0,1489571042,'','::1');

site_plugin_redirects_stats has as primary key stat_id with auto-increment, bellow is the create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE 'site_plugin_redirects_stats' (
  'stat_id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'stat_redirect' int(11) NOT NULL,
  'stat_date' int(11) NOT NULL,
  'stat_from' text NOT NULL,
  'stat_ip' varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  'stat_hostname' varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('stat_id')
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The error i receive should never happen, but i encountered it twice in the past 6 months.

The problem is once i receive it the application will stop running, no other records can be inserted in that table.

Is something related to mysql configuration ? a bug or something maybe ?

First time it happened on a production LAMP server, second time on a local WAMP server.

Comment: Did your server run out of space, suddenly restart in the last 6 month?  in my.cnf is your `innodb_force_recovery` set to `1`?

Comment: Server has enough space , no innodb_force_recovery in my.cnf. It started to act like this suddenly no reset before.  Only solution was to truncate the table to get the app back online.

Comment: Sounds like an index may have gotten corrupted. Try `REPAIR`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, will try next time when/if will happen, right now its a bit too late as i dropped the table :)